# Call .Java files, based on the test case name

Tags: java, junit, webdriver

Environemnt - Java + Junit +WebDriver

My requirement is this:

I have 120 XLS test cases, they are in xls.

(Example ->
1st test case -Discussion_DOcuOne.xls
2nd test case -Discussion_DOcuTwo.xls
etc...)

I have relevant Java files (one .java file for each xls test case).

(Example ->
 
1st test case -Discussion_DOcuOne.java
2nd test case -Discussion_DOcuTwo.java
etc...)

Through Java code, I am reading one by one xls test case.
And I need to call the related .Java file.

if testCaseName=Discussion_DOcuOne,then,
---- I need to call the Discussion_DOcuOne.java file

I have tried switch+case (by assigning numbers to all xls test cases). 
But I need to write 120 case statements, which is not at all practical.

-----Here I stuck. I don't know how to RUN/CALL the specific Java file.

//For example the testCaseName is "Discussion_DOcuOne", I need to call/run the Discussion_DOcuOne.java.

I don't get any idea how to link these two.

Please find the example Java class (nothing but Java code for each manual test case, we call it TEST SCRIPT).

Every .Java file has one method runTestCase(), and I need to call that specific method which belongs to that specific test script.

---------------------- Here is the Discussion_DOcuOne.Java file---------------

```
public class Discussion_DOcuOne(){
String varOne="abc";
String varTwo="efg";

public void runTestCase(){
//do some thing using the variables above
}
}
```

Comment: When you say `call` do you mean run the Java application launcher (eg java.exe) or calling a method in the class ?

Answer (score 0):

just get name of test:

```
String fileName = "Discussion_DOcuOne";
```

then load class

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(fileName);
```

And create instance of Discussion_DOcuOne

```
clazz.newInstance();
```

then cast object to your interface and call your method